# Expected identifier before '=' token

Tags: c, arrays, struct, syntax-error

```
void give_weapon(int adr, int type, int material, int item, int condition)
{
    player_inventory.weapon[adr].type = type;
    player_inventory.weapon[adr].material = material;
    player_inventory.weapon[adr].item = item;
    player_inventory.weapon[adr].condition = condition;
    define_weapon_name(adr);
    player_inventory.weapon[adr].gold_val = define_weapon_gold_value(adr);
    player_inventory.weapon[adr].weight = define_weapon_weight(adr);
}
```

The function in simple. Send information about the weapon you want to give to the player as function arguments and the address (array index) of where you want the weapon to be stored in.
When I execute this code in the source file, it works fine, but because this is another c source file that I had linked, things are somehow different.

The last line, `player_inventory.weapon[adr].weight = define_weapon_weight(adr);`, gives me an error saying `expected identifier before '=' token`. I checked the spelling, the return type of the function I am calling and the structure itself that I am calling - everything is fine.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Can you show the code for the weapon struct?

Comment: Obviously your player_inventory and weapon types aren't defined as you expect, and we can't possibly fix that without seeing the definitions.

Comment: Is there a macro `weight` defined somewhere in the problematic source file? E.g `#define weight 42`

Comment: Better yet, please provide [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AnT thanks that was the problem. Just gonna change the code...

Comment: @octagonlord69: Well... Avoid by all costs defining sneaky macros with such innocent-looking names. Macro names should stand out. "All caps" is a popular convention.

Comment: One way to avoid this sort of problem is to make your macro definitions be in CAPS. Another way to avoid the problem is to let your structure members have some distinguishing prefix or suffix (like `w_name`, `w_type`, ..., `w_weight`).